# Movie about a spaceship that leaves Earth to find a new home but ends up back at Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a movie I saw a few years ago.

It's about a spaceship, that left Earth to find a new home. But something went wrong. So they ended up on Earth years later. They crash into Earth's protection Grid. (They only find out in the end)

The rest of the human population is taken captured by "aliens", and they are capturing the crew off the spaceship.

In the end they finally leave orbit. To only to find out they are on Earth.